# Log into facebook from a prism app

Tags: facebook, mozilla-prism

I'm trying to open Turntable.fm in a prism app, but it says I need to log in to Facebook, and every time I click on the button Google Chrome opens to authorize Turntable.

I tried making Turntable the default browser but then clicking on the button just did nothing. How can I get the facebook login button to open inside the Turntable app, or otherwise authorize my account inside the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by linking my turntable.fm with my twitter account too, then using twitter to log in.  Worked fine even though I used my Facebook to originally sign up.